# The command line clang/clang++ doesn't work on MacBook Air 2012 Mid with OS X 10.8.5

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, clang++

Originally, I used clang++ with -std=c++11 compile my C++11 code, everything was OK. Recently, I updated the Xcode in  AppStore, I compiled the SAME program in command line again, it doesn't work anymore, it shows errors like below:

> /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_construct.h:81:38: error: no matching
>   constructor for initialization of
>         'std::basic_string'
>         ::new(static_cast(__p)) *T1(*_value);

It seems the clang++ is using gcc's header files, apparently, gcc's version is very old. However, if I compile the same program by using Xcode, everything is fine.

It seems, at command line , the clang++ can't find the correct header files anymore.

More information, running command clang++ --version, following output:

> Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) 
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 Thread model: posix

which clang++

> /usr/bin/clang++

**RESOLVED with option -stdlib=libc++**

Comment: Check and see if xcode is setting the include path?

Comment: can you post your call to clang

Comment: What happens if you compile using `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++`?